# Image uploads broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Title says it all. When I try to upload an image in a post, it just says that, "An error occurred at imgur"

<strike>*Funny thing is, I can't even provide a screenshot of the error because I can't upload pictures!*</strike>

**UPDATE:** The error went away after restarting Firefox.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question of no repro

Comment: Do we actually close no-repro questions on meta?

Comment: @KazWolfe: Maybe you should ask on Meta! ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) on Chrome 57.0.2987.133.