# Nothing to review? What gives?

Tags: bug, status-completed

This UTC morning I looked at the reviews page and saw about 100 Close Votes to review and nothing else. Thinking this was slightly odd, I nonetheless reviewed 20 close-voted questions in the queue, then checked again. Still nothing!

Several hours later, I still see all zeroes in the review queues, apart from the greyed-out Close Votes, although the orange items-to-review indicator in the toolbar (the one that shows suggested edits to review when you have =>2k and all items to review whether you're able to review them or not when you have =>10k) shows me 115 items.

I thought maybe I had been silently review-banned for some reason (haven't failed any audits lately that I recall) but if I look at the history pages of the queues, I can't see any recent reviewing activity, so maybe it's not just me.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Slow weekends, I suppose

Comment: Something does seem broken.. I wonder if this has something to do with SE's move back to Denver.

Comment: I see 112 close votes to review and I can access them fine. Either they fixed it or it's specific to your user or something. Is this still an issue for you?

Comment: @terdon I can see the close votes (76) greyed out because I've done 20 - that's normal. Everything else is (still) zero which is really exceptional, even for a weekend

Comment: I see 92 close votes and 0 for everything else. Haven't done review in a few days though *looks down and kicks pebbles*

Comment: **zero** in every queue except CV - thats a very singular event - never seen that before.

Comment: I see 0 in all review queues.

Comment: [Same issue on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353665/review-queues-empty) I suspect nothing new is being added since the (always full) CV queue worked but the number is going down

Comment: Yep, the fallback to Denver has caused a few issues. Apparently no scheduled tasks are running. They're working on it.  In the meantime if you want to review there are plenty of close votes, or you can use your 10k tools :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into it @Seth :)

Comment: Seems to work again?

Comment: Indeed :) I was able to review some stuff. And some people are "No Action Needed"ing First Posts and Late Answers as usual :( SNAFU.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **this describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own** or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers...

Comment: @Fabby I don't think we do that with meta posts... there's a meta post about it... [oh here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16916/do-we-actually-close-no-repro-bugs-reported-on-meta-as-no-repro)... but a mod can tag this [status-norepro] to stop people bothering with it

Comment: This was fixed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/353675/1583

Comment: @Zanna That's why I put the smileys in there...  I originally wanted to ping you about it in chat, but you haven't been around lately... The close vote will probably expire before it'll be closed!  **;-)**

Comment: @terdon can this really be no-repro when it was certainly reproduced by many others and then acknowledged and fixed?

Comment: Yeah after Oded edited it I feel it's [completed] and not [no-repro], sounds like I was imagining the whole thing hahaha

Comment: Fair enough, I just added it 'cause you mentioned it above.

Comment: @terdon yeah I know, it was my bad, I don't know the tags properly. Thanks a lot for fixing :)